# Infinite loop in CUDA kernel

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I have a CUDA kernel where every thread traverse a tree. Because of this I have a while loop which is looped until the thread reaches a leaf. In every step down the tree it checks which of the children it should pick to follow.

The code is as follows:

```
__global__ void search(float* centroids, float* features, int featureCount, int *votes)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if(tid < featureCount)
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (index < N) 
        {
            votes[tid] = index;
            int childIndex = index * CHILDREN + 1;
            float minValue = FLT_MAX;

            if(childIndex >= (N-CHILDREN)) break;

            for(int i = 0; i < CHILDREN; i++)
            {
                int centroidIndex = childIndex + i;
                float value = distance(centroids, features, centroidIndex, tid);
                if(value < minValue)
                {
                    minValue = value;
                    index = childIndex + i;
                }
            }
        }
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}

__device__ float distance(float* a, float* b, int aIndex, int bIndex)
{
    float sum = 0.0f;
    for(int i = 0; i < FEATURESIZE; i++)
    {
        float val = a[aIndex + i] - b[bIndex + i];
        sum += val * val;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

This code goes into an infinite loop. That is what I find weird.
If I change the distance method to return a constant it works(ie. traversing left in the tree).

Have I missed something with loops in CUDA or is there just some hidden bug I can't see? Because I don't see how the code can go into an infinite loop.

Comment: There's a hidden bug :) You could try debugging this code by executing it on the host and inspecting which ```tid``` causes the infinite loop.

Comment: What do you mean by executing on the host and inspecting which tid causes the infinite loop? I can only get the tid from device code :) I have tried using "cuPrintf" from nvidea but I am not sure I can trust it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loops in CUDA C++ have the same semantics as they do in C++, so there must be a bug somewhere in your code. One strategy for debugging it would be to do so on the host.

First, because your code is scalar (e.g., it contains no calls to `__syncthreads`), you can refactor it into `__host__ __device__` functions.

`distance` contains no CUDA-specific identifiers or functions, so you can simply prepend `__host__`:

```
__host__ __device__ float distance(float* a, float* b, int aIndex, int bIndex);
```

To refactor your `search` function, hoist `tid` (which depends on the CUDA-specific identifiers `threadIndex` et al.) outside of it into a parameter, and make it a `__host__ __device__` function:

```
__host__ __device__ void search(int tid, float* centroids, float* features, int featureCount, int *votes)
{
  if(tid < featureCount)
  {
    int index = 0;
    while (index < N) 
    {
      votes[tid] = index;
      int childIndex = index * CHILDREN + 1;
      float minValue = FLT_MAX;

      if(childIndex >= (N-CHILDREN)) break;

      for(int i = 0; i < CHILDREN; i++)
      {
        int centroidIndex = childIndex + i;
        float value = distance(centroids, features, centroidIndex, tid);
        if(value < minValue)
        {
          minValue = value;
          index = childIndex + i;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now write a `__global__` function which does nothing except calculate `tid` and call `search`:

```
__global__ void search_kernel(float *centroids, float features, int featureCount, int *votes)
{
  int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  search(tid, centroids, features, featureCount, votes); 
}
```

Because `search` is now `__host__ __device__`, you can debug it by calling it from the CPU, emulating what a kernel launch would do:

```
for(int tid = 0; tid < featureCount; ++tid)
{
  search(tid, centroids, features, featureCount, votes);
}
```

It should hang on the host exactly as it would on the device. Stick a `printf` inside to find out where. Of course, you need to be sure to make host-side copies of your arrays such as `centroids`, because the host cannot dereference pointers to device memory.

Even though `printf` is available to use from `__device__` functions with newer hardware, the reason you might prefer this approach is that calls to `printf` from a kernel do not commit until *after* the kernel retires. If the kernel never retires (as it apparently does not in your case) then your debugging output will never appear on the screen.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of this. This will help alot with debugging I think :)